# General Gamma distribution clarification

Tags: probability, improper-integrals

In my notes defining a general gamma distribution where the "waiting time" is not necessarily an integer it states the following for $\alpha >0$, $\beta >0$:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-\beta t)t^{\alpha -1 }dt=\frac {\Gamma (\alpha)} {\beta ^ \alpha}.$$
I know that the Gamma function is defined as 
$$\Gamma (\alpha) = \int_0^{\infty}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-y}dy,$$
but I am unsure how these two statements are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the next change in your integral $t = s/\beta$ and you will have it!

For clarity

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\textrm{exp}(-\beta t)t^{\alpha-1}dt = \int_{0}^{\infty}\textrm{exp}(-s)\left(\frac{s}{\beta}\right)^{\alpha-1}d\left(\frac{s}{\beta}\right)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^{\alpha}}$$

Comment: would this not yield $Γ(α)/β^{α-1}$

Comment: the differential $d\left(\frac{s}{\beta}\right)=\frac{ds}{\beta}$, and is multiplied by $1/\beta^{\alpha-1}$ yielding $1/\beta^\alpha$.

Comment: keep in mind that $\beta$ is constant